# Overriding a Custom Control's Text Property to use a Textbox's Text causes the Textbox to display the Control's name by default

Tags: vb.net, properties, overriding

Using VB.net (2005), I'm creating a custom control (a folder picker) that contains a textbox and button. Recently I've added the following:

```
<Browsable(True), DefaultValue(""), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)> _
Public Overrides Property Text() As String
    Get
        Return Me.uiPath.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Me.uiPath.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

The problem I'm having is that now when the control is created, the textbox always defaults to showing the name of the control (instead of being blank). It seems the Text property is being changed after Sub New is called, however, I've checked the designer, and I cannot see where it is doing this.

I know that changing the name of the property would resolve the issue, but I would like to know why this is happening (I'm guessing it has something to do with the standard designer?), and if there is a way to resolve (or work around) it, while still using the Text property?

I don't know if it makes any difference, but I am using a custom designer:

```
Public Class FolderPickerDesigner
 Inherits Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner

 Public Overrides ReadOnly Property SnapLines() As IList
    Get
        Dim SnapLinesList As ArrayList = TryCast(MyBase.SnapLines, ArrayList)

        If (Me.Control IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (Me.Control IsNot Nothing) Then
            Dim FP As FolderPicker = CType(Me.Control, FolderPicker)

            SnapLinesList.Add(New SnapLine(SnapLineType.Baseline, FP.uiPath.Bottom - 5, SnapLinePriority.Medium))
        End If

        Return SnapLinesList
    End Get
 End Property

End Class
```

Any help / ideas would be appreciated. If this doesn't / can't be resolved, I'll mark the most helpful post as the answer...

Comment: try bracketing the property name: `Property [Text]`.  does your control inherit from something like UserCOntrol or Component?

Comment: @Plutonix it inherits from UserControl. I did try [Text], but it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

```
Set(ByVal value As String)

If Me.DesignMode And (Environment.StackTrace.Contains("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.InitializeNewComponent")) Then Return

    BaseT.Text = value

End Set
```